# Why is Nicol prism cut at 68 degrees specifically?

Tags: optics, refraction, birefringence

Why not just some other angle but this specific one? Does it help in some way to polarize the ray?

I have tried searching everywhere, but they only show that the crystal is cut at an angle of 68 degrees to the crystal axis and diagonally too, before joining the pieces again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicol_prism explains how the Nicol prism works. First of all, the angle of 68 degrees works for the specific crystal - calcite. If you choose a much larger angle, the ordinary ray (o-ray) will not have a total internal reflection at the diagonal plane, if you choose a much smaller angle, both the extraordinary ray (e-ray) and the o-ray will have a total internal reflection. In both cases you will not have a completely polarized ray. I guess you can choose an angle close to 68 degrees, and the prism will work OK, but I don't think you have a lot of wiggle room, and the ultimate reason is that the refraction indices do not differ much for the e-ray and o-ray (just by 6.5%).

Comment: The e-ray and o-ray refractive indices don't differ much, but the refractive index of Canada balsam (the glue layer) differs from both even less (it's between the two). Also, according to my calculations (which are based on problem 1 after §77 in [Сивухин Д.В. "Общий курс физики. Оптика"](http://alexandr4784.narod.ru/sdvop4.html)), total polarization aperture remains quite useful even for prism angles far from 68°. Maybe peak transmission coefficient would be smaller for other angles, I didn't check.

Comment: @Ruslan : So I offered some qualitative considerations. It does not look like your information makes them incorrect.

Comment: thanks that explains it

Answer (score 0):

The refractive index of the ordinary ray in calcite is n_o = 1.658, and for the extraordinary ray n_e = 1.486 (@590nm). Nicol prism is glued together by a Canada Balsam layer, which has a refractive index of 1.526.

I got a hint why this angle has been preferred after calculating the refractive index experienced by the extraordinary ray in calcite. At 68 deg ray propagation angle (with respect to the optical axis) I obtained n_e ~ 1.529 and it matches the refractive index of the glue very closely. Then the extraordinary ray (entering perpendicular to the face of the polarizer) travels through the prism, glue layer, and another prism with very little reflection.

This is very superficial, because some other things might be at play - one may want to try and maximize the spectral width or the max input angle.
Still, it does not seem a coincidence, especially as the calcite refractive index is quite flat in the visible range, so reflection would be very small for these wavelengths as well.